# How to create a boot hdd and copy windows files onto it?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partition

I have a zip archive containing installed windows xp embedded operating system. 
How can I copy files onto HDD to make it bootable?

I went to disk part, converted hdd to mbr, created primary active partition and copied files over. Still can't boot.

Comment: after creating the mbr structure you need to install the boot manager.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to rebuild MBR. When you used zip and converted HDD to MBR to boot windows will not recognize the path. Hope it will help you!